# Entry with tkinter

Tags: python, api, tkinter, input

I am trying to enter variables to use in an API call app. When I use the normal python input thing, it works, but I want to be able to enter these via the entry widget with tkinter. When I try to use the tkinter entry widget, it does not work.

`

```
import API_test
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import random
import requests
from tkinter.ttk import *

##root for Tkinter app
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x400")

with open('inputfile.txt', 'w') as fp:
    fp.truncate(0)

stringvar1 = tkinter.StringVar()
stringvar2 = tkinter.StringVar()

##tkinter labels
L1 = tkinter.Label(text="Enter City ",)
L2 = tkinter.Label(text = "Enter Cuisine ",)

##tkinter entry 
rootentry1 = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=stringvar1)
rootentry2 = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=stringvar2)
###buttoninput
##tkinter button
##tkinter label and entry placement
L1.grid(row=0,column=0)
rootentry1.grid(row=0,column=1)

L2.grid(row=1,column=0)
rootentry2.grid(row=1,column=1)

def inputfile():
   locvarentry = stringvar1
   catvarentry = stringvar2
   with open('inputfile.txt', 'w') as fw:
       fw.write(str(locvarentry)+ ",")
       fw.write(str(catvarentry)+ ",")

B1 = tkinter.Button( root,rtext="Submit", command=inputfile)
B1.grid(row=3, column=0)
```

The rest of the program has an API call using yelp in a different module and returns a display saying that the number of  restaurants in  is . I have that covered, but I am not sure how to handle the input.
`

I tried playing around with variables, using .get() and .set() in different combinations.

Comment: you have to use `stringvar1.get()` to get value from `StringVar`

Comment: what means `does not work`? Do you get error message? Show it in question (not in comments). Do you get wrong value? Show it in question (not in comments). Don't expect that we will run code to see problem. Besides it can work correctly on our computers. And we can't read in your mind. You have to describe all details in question (not in comments)

Comment: if you tried to use `.get()`,`.set()` then show this code in question - and we can show you where you made mistake.

Comment: if this is all of your code then you forgot `root.mainloop()`.

Comment: when you open file with `write mode` to write data then it automatically truncate it to `0` - you don't have to do it manually. OR you can `open` and `close` without `truncate` and you get empty file.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter
##root for Tkinter app
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x400")

stringvar1 = tkinter.StringVar()
stringvar2 = tkinter.StringVar()

##tkinter labels
L1 = tkinter.Label(text="Enter City ",)
L2 = tkinter.Label(text = "Enter Cuisine ",)

##tkinter entry
rootentry1 = tkinter.Entry(root)
rootentry2 = tkinter.Entry(root)
###buttoninput
##tkinter button
##tkinter label and entry placement
L1.grid(row=0,column=0)
rootentry1.grid(row=0,column=1)

L2.grid(row=1,column=0)
rootentry2.grid(row=1,column=1)

def inputfile():
   locvarentry = rootentry1.get()
   catvarentry = rootentry2.get()
   print(str(locvarentry)+ ",")
   print(str(catvarentry)+ ",")

B1 = tkinter.Button( root, text="Submit", command=inputfile)
B1.grid(row=3, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

What do you think of this? I removed the opening of the file for making the testing easier, so just implement this if it works...

Comment: this works for getting input from the input file, but now the rest of the program doesn't work. When I add mainloop to the end, it does not work, but when I have it after the def inputfile(), it only handles the input.

Answer (score 0):

Code works for me when I use `.get()` in

```
locvarentry = stringvar1.get()
catvarentry = stringvar2.get()
```

And it needs `root.mainloop()` to work.

---

Full code:

```
import API_test
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import random
import requests
from tkinter.ttk import *

##root for Tkinter app
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x400")

with open('inputfile.txt', 'w') as fp:
    fp.truncate(0)

stringvar1 = tkinter.StringVar()
stringvar2 = tkinter.StringVar()

##tkinter labels
L1 = tkinter.Label(text="Enter City ",)
L2 = tkinter.Label(text="Enter Cuisine ",)

##tkinter entry 
rootentry1 = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=stringvar1)
rootentry2 = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=stringvar2)
###buttoninput
##tkinter button
##tkinter label and entry placement
L1.grid(row=0,column=0)
rootentry1.grid(row=0,column=1)

L2.grid(row=1,column=0)
rootentry2.grid(row=1,column=1)

def inputfile():
   locvarentry = stringvar1.get()
   catvarentry = stringvar2.get()
   print(locvarentry, catvarentry)
   with open('inputfile.txt', 'w') as fw:
       fw.write(str(locvarentry)+ ",")
       fw.write(str(catvarentry)+ ",")

B1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Submit", command=inputfile)
B1.grid(row=3, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

The same code but little cleaner:

```
# PEP8: first built-in modules, next external modules, next your modules.
#import random
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` not preferred
#import tk.ttk as ttk  # PEP8: `import *` not preferred
#import requests
#import API_test

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions before main code

def inputfile():
    with open('inputfile.txt', 'w') as fw:  # it will truncate file automatically
        fw.write(stringvar1.get()+ ","+stringvar2.get()+ ",")
    #root.destroy()   # if you want to close window after writing file

# --- main ---

#with open('inputfile.txt', 'w') as fp:  # it will truncate file automatically even if you use `pass` instead of `truncate`
#    fp.truncate(0)

# ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x400")

stringvar1 = tk.StringVar(root)   # it is good to set `master` for all objects in `tkinter`
stringvar2 = tk.StringVar(root)   # it is good to set `master` for all objects in `tkinter`

L1 = tk.Label(text="Enter City ")
L2 = tk.Label(text="Enter Cuisine ")

rootentry1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=stringvar1)
rootentry2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=stringvar2)

L1.grid(row=0, column=0)           # PEP8: space after comma
rootentry1.grid(row=0, column=1)   # PEP8: space after comma

L2.grid(row=1, column=0)           # PEP8: space after comma
rootentry2.grid(row=1, column=1)   # PEP8: space after comma

B1 = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=inputfile)
B1.grid(row=3, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)